# How to rebase a dev branch after merging the PR in git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Let's say this is my master :

C1 -> C2

I made a dev (or feature) branch and did a few commits :

C1 -> C2 -> D1 -> D2 -> D3

Now I raised a PR but by then the master had a few more commits :

C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4

I squashed and merged the PR, now master looks like:

C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> **D**

I might do some more enhancements on the dev branch now, so what git operations I should perform so that my dev branch is same as my master branch now :

[right now] C1 -> C2 -> D1 -> D2 -> D3

[want this] C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> D

Additional Question: Would 'Rebase and Merge' instead of 'Squash and Merge' helped here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your local master branch to what the remote one is:

```
git fetch
git switch master
git reset --hard origin/master
git switch -C dev master
```

Your `dev` branch is now at `master`, itself reset to origin/master: `C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> D`

Since there was no conflicts detected between the original dev you pushed and master, 'Rebase and Merge' would not have helped, and would have resulted in:

```
C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> D1' -> D2' -> D3'
```